# Trouble understanding the flow of data in a PHP file which uses both server side and client side scripting

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am creating a wordpress plugin where a shortcode can be added to a page which when loaded will display a chart for a chosen user, using that user's data in the wordpress database.

Currently, when the page is loaded, a PHP function executes a couple of SQL queries to create 2 arrays that are then passed as JSON objects to some javascript that dynamically displays two drop-down lists (populated by appropriate data from the arrays). This all works fine and the drop downs display perfectly.

Elsewhere in my PHP file I have php functions that generate charts using charts.js for a given user after it is passed a user ID number. This code also works well when run separately, displaying a graph on the webpage.

My issue is that I need my PHP file to be able to access the user that is chosen from the drop-down list and pass it to another PHP function to generate the graph and display it under the drop-downs.

Now I know JS is client side and PHP is server side. Therefore the only way to pass a JS variable to the PHP is to make an AJAX call. I have this working following the drop-down selection, but the problem is that the PHP file has already been executed. So even though the php file receives the chosen user data in a php variable, which is passed to the graph creation PHP functions, the web page will not update with the graph as the php file has already been executed.

My question is, what possible options do I have here?

My aim is to have a shortcode that displays drop downs and once the user selects a person from the list, the charts for that user are displayed underneath.

Do I need to rewrite my php graph creation functions (that have SQL queries and subsequent PHP calculations) so they are written in pure JS and executed straight after the drop-down select form is submitted (removing the requirement for having the chosen user data in a php variable),  or is there a way that I can still use my graph creating PHP functions that reside in the same PHP file so they display the graph under the drop down once a person is selected from the list?

Comment: You basically need to separate responsibilities between php scripts. One script would be to generate site with dropdown controls - so called "front end", others would be to provide chart data on ajax requests, that will be received by forst part and orchestrated with JS. You have some more reading about AJAX or AJAJ ahead

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense. I think I now know how to generate the correct flow of data without having to re-write too much code. Many thanks